# How much pt is headings=small?

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, koma-script

I am using this code for my seminar paper:

`\documentclass[headings=small,fontsize=12pt,a4paper,oneside,]{scrreprt}`

but I was wondering: how many pt are `headings=small`? It looks like 14pt but I am not sure.

My `\chapter` has to be 14pt and the written text 12pt. Is there a overview for this like huge, large, normal, tiny,...?

Comment: If you do `\chapter{\fontname\font}` you get "cmssbx10 at 17.28pt". Use `\setkomafont`, see section 3.2 in the manual.

Answer (score 8):

KOMA-Script uses the class option file `scrsize12pt.clo` With option `fontsize=12pt`. It defines (fontsize/baselineskip):

- `\normalsize`: 12pt/14.5pt
- `\small`: 11pt/13.6pt
- `\footnotesize`: 10pt/12pt
- `\scriptsize`: 8pt/9.5pt
- `\tiny`: 6pt/8pt
- `\large`: 14pt/18pt
- `\Large`: 17pt/22pt
- `\LARGE`: 20pt/25pt
- `\huge`: 25pt/30pt
- `\Huge`: \huge

Class `scrrprt.cls` uses with option `headings=small` the following sizes for the section headings:

- `\part`: `\LARGE`
- `\chapter`: `\Large`
- `\section`: `\large`
- `\subsection`: `\normalsize`
- `\subsubsection`: `\normalsize`
- `\paragraph`: `\normalsize`
- `\subparagraph`: `\normalsize`

The documentation contains a table with the different font sizes for the section commands with different settings of option `headings` (`scrguien.pdf`, 2012-07-22):

> Table 3.15.: Default font sizes for different levels of document
>   structuring in scrbook and scrreprt

Thus your `\section` has font size 14pt. The font size for the chapter can be redefined, e.g.:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\size@chapter}{\large}
\makeatother
```

Or probably better, using the official interface:

```
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\large}
```

Comment: Ok for confirmation that I have understood right: `fontsize=12` means my written text is 12pt and in addtion `headings=small` affects which sizes are used for \part, \chapter and so on?

Comment: @sceiler `fontsize=12` means the base font size including the written text (`\normalsize`) and yes, `headings=small` affectys the sizes for `\part`, `\chapter` ...